# Modifying Wireless components of a network, to become Wired

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I'm wanting to change the configuration of my home network. A partial schematic of the network is as follows:

[image: current network]

when I say "partial" there are other things connected to the ADSL router which for simplicity, I've left out.

Please pay particular attention to the "Wireless Client"s at the bottom. I want to change their configuration such that the network looks like this:

[image: desired network]

So you can see, I want to make these clients *wired* clients, which will go into some box (marked ?????), and to have that box talk to the wireless network.

My question is firstly, is it possible? Assuming it is possible, what type of hardware does "?????" need to be? Or, do I need a couple of pieces of hardware?

*I will pre-empt the question "why" by giving a little background. Currently, "Wireless Client #1" and "Wireless Client #2" are not computers, but are satellite tv receivers. Neither has wireless functionality, I currently (for each of them) have a wireless bridge dongle going into the RJ45 socket, thereby allowing them to talk out to the wlan and ultimately to the web. I'm looking at getting some more clients of this type, and I don't really want to buy a dongle for each. I'd sooner sit some kind of router/access point/bridge with the receivers under the tv, and have that router/access point/bridge communicate with the wireless network on the clients' behalf. But I'n not exactly sure what that box needs to be.*

Lastly, the obvious option of plumbing into the adsl router amd bypassing the wireless network altogether, I'm put off this option purely because of the geography of the house. I'm not really ina position to lay cables right now.

Comment: I'd be curious how the bandwidth of two wireless clients to a single WAP compared to the speeds the clients could get connected to a wireless bridge . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, very possible. Set up the second wireless router in *bridge mode* — it then becomes an extension of your LAN (two routers, one LAN). Then connect the clients by Ethernet to the second wireless router.

Many routers do this out of the box, otherwise, you can use alternative firmware to get the functionality (e.g. DD-WRT — [instructions and schematic](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged)). An router [with DD-WRT built-in](http://www.flashrouters.com/routers/brands/cisco-linksys/cisco-linksys-e1200-ddwrt-router#best2014) would make it easy.

Comment: So the router wireless can act as the bridge provider??? I thought you had to use one of the LAN ports? Hmm.. Excellent!

Comment: Thanks. In fact I've since found [an article](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/resource-centre/how-to-guides/how-to-extend-your-network-with-a-wireless-bridge) on Dlink's site which points me in exactly that direction. They're plugging their own piece of kit but I reckon I can get the same thing with an access point (acting as a bridge) and an old switch I've got lying around.